# Ruby Loop through some attributes of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, metaprogramming

In Rails, I have a class name `User`, in which I just want to look at `:name, :address, :age`

I would like to write a piece of code that's something like:

```
user = User.new
[name, address, age].zip(["Name", "Address", 10]).each do |attribute, val|
  user.attribute = val
end
```

The thing is I don't know how to do it properly, since `user.attribute` is obviously not a valid line. In other word, is there anyway so that `user.attribute` gets evaluated as `user.name`, `user.address`, `user.age` depends on the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `send` method

```
user.send "#{attribute}=", val
```

If attribute is, say, `:name`, then the line above is equivalent to

```
user.name = val
```

Comment: I'd use `send` as last resort, Rails provides `write_attribute(attribute, value)`.

Comment: Oh yes, he did actually mention rails. Just not in the tags :)

Comment: check again :-p. It's ok to show `send` as the basic metaprogramming method, but given that the OP is using rails we can mention both (and another way in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can do it this way:

```
[name, address, age].zip(["Name", "Address", 10]).each do |attribute, val|
    user[attribute] = val
end
```

This way works, too

Answer (score 1):

`user.send(:name)` would be the same as calling `user.name`, so you may want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
user = User.new
[name, address, age].zip(["Name", "Address", 10]).each do |attribute, val|
  user.write_attribute(attribute, val)
end
```

But that's what I'd write:

```
user = User.new
user.attributes = {name => "Name", address => "Address", age => 10}
```